# How to move nav items off the screen when viewing on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobile, responsive

I am learning how to build the hamburger menu for mobile devices.

I have built a navigation that has three children. Logo, nav-items and hamburger menu. I used flexbox to position them side-by-side and display: none on hamburger menu on desktop to hide it initially.

I tried playing around with position relative/absolute, but it's not quite working. Also, changing flex-direction: row to column won't help.

Here's the markup for the navbar

```
<nav class="nav">
  <div class="brand"><h4>The Brand</h4></div>

  <div class="navigation">
    <ul class="navigation__list">
      <li class="navigation__item">
        <a href="#">Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__item">
        <a href="#">About</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__item">
        <a href="#">Services</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__item">
        <a href="#">Gallery</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__item">
        <a href="#">Blog</a>
      </li>
      <li class="navigation__item">
        <a href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>

  <button class="hamburger">
    <span class="hamburger__box">
      <span class="hamburger__inner"></span>
    </span>
  </button>
</nav>
```

What I want to achive is: On mobile devies, the hamburger menu should appear. The nav items should dissapear off the screen and should be placed vertically. I want them to slide in from the right when hamburger is clicked.

codepen: https://codepen.io/kowalik9412/pen/WNeMQrO

Answer (score 0):

Just use bootstrap.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-xrRywqdh3PHs8keKZN+8zzc5TX0GRTLCcmivcbNJWm2rs5C8PRhcEn3czEjhAO9o" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">



<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-white">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><h4>The Brand</h4></a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
      </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Services</a>
      </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Gallery</a>
      </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blog</a>
      </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </li>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score -1):

you have to toggle a class in navigation div class list. your javascript code is as below.

```
const handleClick = () => {
  navigation.classList.toggle("show");
};
```

and you have to add media css for to navigation class. the media css code is as below.

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
  .navigation.show {
    display: none;
  }
  .navigation.show {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

then after your have to set the remaining design as per your requirement. this code is just help you to hide menu initially in mobile device and open it while you click on to burger menu button.

Thank you.